# Google Places API Error1

Tags: google-places-api

I am getting following error message:

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
>   key. Request received from IP address 203.196.191.151, with empty
>   referer", html_attributions: [ ], results: [ ], status:
>   "REQUEST_DENIED"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as stated in the documentation for Javascript (ie browser based) API keys:

> Restrict your API keys to be used by only the IP addresses, referrer
>   URLs, and mobile apps that need them: By restricting the IP addresses,
>   referrer URLs, and mobile apps that can use each key, you can reduce
>   the impact of a compromised API key.

The key you are using has such a restriction on it. Set the required IP or referrer in the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

> You can specify the hosts and apps that can use each key from the
>   console by opening the Credentials page and then either creating a new
>   API key with the settings you want, or editing the settings of an API
>   key.

Comment: Thank You. Now its working fine only. Because of that API key only issue came